# Getting old values from variables and state

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

Hi am using firebase and react hooks,
The issue that I see that I am getting old state or not updated variables (guests / foreUpdate) inside fuction

```
//table that update the data
 onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
                  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                      //the upodated  values are here 
                      setGuests([...dataUpdate]);
                      foreUpdate=false;
                      firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
             
                     
                      resolve();
                    }, 500);
                  }),
```

the code that not getting updated is :

```
  const changeDbChangesEvents = () => {
        commentsRef.on("child_changed", (data) => {
    if (guests && foreUpdate) {  // 2 values arent updated. foreUpdate - is simple varibale not state
          const cloneGuests = _.cloneDeep(guests);
            setGuests(cloneGuests);
          }
          foreUpdate=true;
        });
```

Comment: can you check if the `onRowUpdate` function is working as expected or not. Also, can you tell more about `setGuests([...dataUpdate])`, what exactly is `dataUpdate` here? Is it dependent on previous state?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using old state because you execute the code ony after the other. Try to put your database change code into a `useEffect` like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
}, [updates]);
```

That ensures that you run the update only with the newest values.

Comment: in that case I will update all collection and not just one item...

Comment: Can you sahre kore about your workflow and more code snippets.